# Binder for long{} in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonActionResult <BaseAsyncResponse> Add(long[] IdList) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < IdList.Length; i++) 
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

```
var o = {
  url: addButton.action.url,
  method: addButton.action.method,
  params: {
    'IdList': Ext.encode(allIds)
  }
};
Ext.Ajax.request(o);
```

> I am trying to pass a long[] to code behind from an Ajax call. The IdList currently comes in as a string which I convert into a JsonArray. Is there a ways to use the bind attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use DefaultModelBinder your request content should look like:

```
IdList[0]=100&IdList[1]=200&IdList[2]=300&IdList[3]=400&...&IdList[n]=...
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on this?